How to make two overlapping mat-sliders moveable?
I want to have two overlapping mat-sliders, but when I set it in below way,I'm able to move only second one...
<h1>EXAMPLE</h1>

<div class="sliders-wrapper">
  <mat-slider class="first-slider">
    <input matSliderThumb />
  </mat-slider>
  <mat-slider class="second-slider">
    <input matSliderThumb />
  </mat-slider>
</div>

<style>
  .sliders-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .first-slider {
    position: absolute;
    }
</style>


I know that mat-sliders provides way to create this kind of stuff by putting two inputs inside one mat-slider, but I want to be able to move both of them in above way.
Here is stackblitz example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-defaultsort-qgjzf4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsort-overview-example.html

due to the rule of z-index, there can be only one above and one below so its not possible
